# Why is Bridge edge loop not complete?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edges

I am trying to create a bridge edge loop to attach a finger to a hand. But its not fully bridging here are the vertices before bridging:[image]

this is how it looks like when trying to bridge:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like you've selected only 3 vertices on the bottom part? Also, make sure you have the good settings in the Operator box

Comment: also, check the actual vertex-count on the loops, to make sure there are no hidden double-verts, etc.

Comment: @RobinBetts I have followed your comment but still no results. is there a way we can interact live so that I can show you

Comment: @moonboots I made that mistake when taking the snapshot. but if while selecting it, it doesnt work

Comment: Its fine i found another way thanks!